# Was Star Trek's original Captain Kirk always fond of antiques?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, captain-kirk

In *The Wrath of Kahn* (*TWOK*), there are at least 2 references to Kirk's fondness for antiques.  Spock states that he's aware of this fondness when he gives him an old edition of *A Tale of Two Cities*; McCoy tells him to get away from his antiques and get his command back, and I think there's a reference to this as well when McCoy gives Kirk his reading glasses (along with a reference to Kirk's medication allergy).

I grew up watching the original series (some during the original run and all, many times, in reruns) and had seen all of the animated series when *TWOK* came out — and had endured *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* several times as well.  I remember when I was watching *TWOK* in the movie theater for the first time being "jarred" by the lines about antiques.  While it was not out of place, I don't remember any reference to such an interest in any preceding Trek at that time.

It's quite believable that, as he aged, and was no longer on a ship, that Kirk had time on his hands and needed a hobby or to become drawn to out-of-date objects — since he may have felt past his usefulness, so it's not that such a reference is wrong or out of place.  But I have long wondered if I missed something along the way.

Excluding books (which the producers rarely counted as canon), was this interest of Kirk's ever mentioned before *TWOK*?  And, as long as I'm asking, was it in any of the very few Trek books that had been published before *TWOK* either?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to a [de Forest Research](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kellam_de_Forest) memo for Star Trek: The Wrath of Khan from October 14, 1981:

> Kirk has NEVER collected antiques. Perhaps a line might be planted that he has developed a new interest. (One of the problems with the Kirk character is that he was never consistently written. He was always what the writers needed THAT week.)

The quote was [found here](http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?p=7876387). The poster said:

> UCLA has many of [de Forest's] memos from the original series in the Roddenberry papers. The one from TWOK is in the [Nick Meyer papers](https://www.lib.uiowa.edu/scua/msc/tomsc450/msc425/msc425.html) at the University of Iowa.

Comment: Think this clearly fits into the pattern. Also, if you compare several episodes and movies there are lots of different levels of "knowledge" regarding the past. For example, in **Spectre of the Gun** Spock and Kirk are immediately able to judge the surroundings to resemble 1880's wild west, including details about history. They act in a similar way in other episodes essentially showcasing alternate realities (knowledge about 1930's mafia stuff or the Nazi regime). On the other hand, they've got lots of issues in **The Voyage Home**, where they at once forgot about money and other things.

Comment: I would add that taking rare and valuable antiques on board a starship in the rough-and-tumble 23rd century is not such a bright idea. (The 24th is different: Picard's Enterprise takes *children* on board - clearly it is considered less dangerous.) Once on a starbase, Kirk could safely collect them.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't check this as the answer when you first posted it, but I did it now.  Apologies for the oversight.

Comment: I prefer the work of Shatner de Willum to that of Kellam de Forest.

Answer (score 16):

It's notable that *Tale of Two Cities* is literature, not simply an antique. References to Kirk's interest in literature comes up several times. Examples: In "Where No Man Has Gone Before," Gary tells Kirk he's had time in sickbay to read some of the "long-haired" stuff that his friend had been recommending. In "The Ultimate Computer," Kirk quotes John Masefield: "And all I ask is a tall ship and a star to steer her by" (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/John_Masefield). In "Space Seed" Kirk and Khan briefly chat about Milton, and Kirk even quotes from *Paradise Lost*."

This may partially explain the nature of that particular antique.